# Passing javascript variable to php using Ajax : showing token error

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i want to pass the javascript variable to php value.

```
var price_values = "1234";
```

### My ajax code is:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {   
        //do 
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "HomePage.php?var="+price_values, true);
xhttp.send();
```

### My php code is:

```
$newMessage = $_GET['var'];
```

I wrote this php code inside form post method .

it showing

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlqR8.png)

Please help me to resolve this

Comment: Not related to your error message (don't think we have enough code to see where that's coming from), but your JS is sending a GET request, not POST. Use `$_GET`.

Comment: i changed into  get,but still showing same error.if i use isset it prints empty

Comment: Not enough code to comment further I don't think.

Comment: `I wrote this php code inside form post method .` - What? Anyways your error is a javascript error.. can you show your whole file and surrounding js code? Your error should point to a line too.. e.g. Unexpected token < on line X

Comment: here i attached my error image.I didn't write anything here but it shows some <br> code

Comment: @AnuPriya can you share more of your code. From your image it says index var is undefined on line no 164. what is your code on line no.164 ??

Comment: the error you've written in the question and the error in the picture are not the same. It looks to me however like you may have written some HTML inside a `<script>` block....this block can only contain JavaScript code. This would explain the "SyntaxError" message. You need to close the script block with `</script>` before you write any more HTML. Alternatively if you're trying to use JavaScript to create new HTML, you need to create it as a string and then append it to an element (you can find plenty of tutorials on that subject)

Comment: the "undefined index" message is being generated and displayed by PHP somehow,  but since you haven't shown any PHP code from that mentioned page we can't say exactly what the issue is. Given it's complaining about the word `var`, which is used in JavScript, I have a nasty feeling you may be jumbling up your JavaScript, HTML and PHP code all together without properly separating it or declaring the right variables or something. We will almost certainly need to see more of the code to sort it out. It's unclear whether the AJAX request actually has any relevance to the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have set a too high error reporting level for your server (either E_NOTICE or E_STRICT, not sure). If you do not want to lower it you will need to change your code like this:

```
$newMessage = isset($_GET['var']) ? $_GET['var'] : NULL;
```